# How to find the difference between two tables in different databases

Tags: database, oracle, comparison

I need to structurally compare two tables in two different databases. the second database is actually an updated version of the first table, and so the structure is approximately the same, but there is some slight differences. Is there any way to automatically compare these tables?

Comment: You can make use of the table ALL_TAB_COLS

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [Create Database Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) to access the table in the other database.

For example,

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "MY_DB_LINK"
  CONNECT TO &username 
  IDENTIFIED BY &pasword 
  USING 'my_service_name';
```

**create tnsnames entry for my_service_name**

```
my_service_name =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = service_name)
    )
  )
```

And then,

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM   user_tab_columns@my_db_link -- here using dblink 
WHERE  table_name = Upper('&table1') 
MINUS 
SELECT column_name --, data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision FROM   user_tab_columns 
WHERE  table_name = Upper('&table2');
```